# Linear Estimation for Rows In Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset that looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2016-12-31','2017-03-31','2017-06-30','2017-02-15'],'Business':['FRC','FICC','FRC','FICC']\
              ,'Amount':[10,100,20,200]})
df
```

Given any date between these dates, I wanted to get the linear value corresponding to these dates. So, for example , if I had one additional date, the Amount that I am looking for would be 15:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2016-12-31','2017-03-31','2017-06-30','2017-02-15','2017-03-31'],'Business':['FRC','FICC','FRC','FICC','FRC']\
              ,'Amount':[10,100,20,200,15]})
df
```

So for each Amount that needs to be calculated, the two neighbouring dates will need to be used to calculate the estimated amount. Any ideas on the best way to achieve this in Pandas ?

Comment: Are the initial Amounts also linear? for example: is it possible for the Amounts to be `[100,200,400]` instead of `[100,200,300]` in your example?

Comment: Hi,Initial amounts are not linear.

Comment: So actually I have to find the 2 dates "around" the new date, and use their amounts to calculate the new amount. Correct? Could you please edit your question to clarify that?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `set_index()`, `reindex()` and `interpolate()`.

```
df = df.set_index('Date').reindex(['2016-12-31','2017-02-15','2017-03-31','2017-05-15','2017-06-30'])

df['Amount'].interpolate(inplace=True)

df

Out[3]:

            Amount
Date    
2016-12-31  100.0
2017-02-15  150.0
2017-03-31  200.0
2017-05-15  250.0
2017-06-30  300.0
```

Edit:

To accommodate a multiindex, set the index as before, reindex with the dates and business required and then sort on the index. Then you can groupby business and linearly interpolate.

```
df.set_index(['Date', 'Business'], inplace=True)
df = df.reindex([('2016-12-31', 'FRC'), ('2017-03-31', 'FICC'), ('2017-06-30', 'FRC'), ('2017-02-15', 'FICC'), ('2017-03-31', 'FRC')])
df.sort_index(level=[1, 0], inplace=True)

df.groupby('Business')['Amount'].transform(lambda x: x.interpolate()).to_frame()

Out[6]:

                      Amount
Date        Business    
2017-02-15  FICC      200.0
2017-03-31  FICC      100.0
2016-12-31  FRC       10.0
2017-03-31  FRC       15.0
2017-06-30  FRC       20.0
```

Comment: Thanks ! Was wondering how to add a second attribute (Business) to the index ? I have modified the original question.

Comment: You can set the index to create a multiindex, reindex as before, sort on the index and then interpolate within groups. See my edit.